# How to allow modules that have missing .d.ts type definition?

Tags: typescript, import

I'm using some unpopular modules such as `Dyo` and `js-sha3` which doesn't have any types, it seems.

I don't really care right now about types in third-party libraries, I don't want to spend hours typing those. I mainly use it for the server to limit my mistakes and make troubleshooting easier while in development.

I had a `Cannot find module X` error before so I've added: `"moduleResolution": "node"` in my tsconfig.json file.

How can I make typescript not complaining about node modules missing types?

The whole error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'dyo'. '/node_modules/dyo/dist/dyo.umd.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/dyo` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'dyo';` [7016]
```

I found `// @ts-nocheck` in a comment in some dark place of the web but it doesn't seem to work.

Can I turn this off by modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create dummy `.d.ts` definition which will allow to import anything from the module - importing it will result in `dyo` having `any` type (the exact way to import it depends on the `esModuleInterop` compiler setting, and on how the things are exported from `dyo.umd.js`).

1. create a file `dyo.d.ts` somewhere within your project with one line in it

   ```
   declare module 'dyo';
   ```
2. in a file that references that module, add this line at the top, with appropriate path to `dyo.d.ts` file:

   ```
   /// <reference path='./dyo.d.ts' />
   ```

An alternative to 2. is to add `dyo.d.ts` to the list of the files included in the compilation in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"files": [
    ... other files as necessary ...

    "./path/to/dyo.d.ts"
]
```

Comment: I did go with the `files` approach to avoid modifying modules files that may break during updates later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For whoever does not want to create their own `.d.ts` definition files, you can use `"noImplicitAny": false` in `tsconfig.json` to allow using external libraries without TypeScript definition files.

Example :

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
    "noImplicitAny": false,
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

This allows TypeScript to infer `any` type from every missing type, hence this will also affect your own project.