# How to include missing type definition files in typescript configuration?

Tags: typescript

This is the same issue as [How to allow modules that have missing .d.ts type definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173833/how-to-allow-modules-that-have-missing-d-ts-type-definition)

VS Code stopped complaining after adding those files, but trying to compile using `gulp` sadly throw an error in the console.

(In fact today I noticed VS code stopped displaying most of the errors)

In `./src/dts/` I have:

**dyo.d.ts**

```
declare module 'dyo';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016", "es2017.object"],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    //"noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/dts",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./src/dts/dyo.d.ts",
    "./src/dts/randomseed.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The error:

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'dyo'.
>   '/mediatest/node_modules/dyo/dist/dyo.umd.js' implicitly has an 'any'
>   type.   Try `npm install @types/dyo` if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'dyo';`

I include the modules like so:

`import { h, render } from 'dyo'`

`import * as _rng from 'random-seed'`

The second module isn't working either.

The previous answer suggested to include `files` property and another question somewhere said to include the `typeRoots` property but both settings doesn't seem to be working.

Sorry for spamming SO about my typescript questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest switching to `types` from `typeRoots` and using an `include` pattern rather than `files`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016", "es2017.object"],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I included the `node` type as well since you are using `node` module resolution, be sure to install `@types/node` if you have not already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've installed `@types/node` and change the configuration, but I still get `Try `npm install @types/dyo` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'dyo';`` :/

Comment: I found the cause of it, gulp-typescript doesn't use tsconfig.json. I was able to change it's configuration to use the file. Finally. Thanks, it helped a lot.

Comment: You can bypass this in TypeScript configuration by using `noImplicitAny: false`, see here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65687243/6380030