# TypeScript Definitions for Forge Viewer missing getFragmentProxy

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using typescript definitions for Forge in link below:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/typescript-definitions-forge-viewer-and-nodejs-client-sdk-now-available

When I try to transform the model following this article:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/know-how-complex-component-transformations-viewer-part-1-basics, I realize `viewerimpl` is missing method `getFragmentProxy`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for letting us know. This issue is caused by the missing type definition for the `Viewer3DImpl#getFragmentProxy` in the community contributed TypeScript definition file for the Forge Viewer (i.e. `@types/forge-viewer`) under [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), so the TypeScript type checker/complier cannot find the type definition. The method is still there in the Forge Viewer JavaScript libs. To fix it, here are some suggestions for you:

- Create an PR for adding the missing type definition of the `Viewer3DImpl#getFragmentProxy` on [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) yourself
- Create a dummy `.d.ts` file to add the missing type definition somewhere in your code project. Please refer here for How-To ([Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54174427/7745569) & [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263204/how-to-include-missing-type-definition-files-in-typescript-configuration))
- Wait for updates on `@types/forge-viewer` from us (**Not recommended**, it might take some time for one line code update)